# To get Validation Messages from the Controller

Tags: validation, jsf, controller

I am using JSF 2.This is my controller.

```
package com.acc.validations;

import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.faces.application.FacesMessage;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.SessionScoped;
@ManagedBean(name="user")
@SessionScoped
public class Controller implements Serializable{

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
String name;
String password;

public String getName() {
    return name;
}
public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
public String getPassword() {
    return password;
}
public void setPassword(String password) {
    this.password = password;
}

private String checkUser(String name,String password) {

    if(("admin".equalsIgnoreCase(name)) && ("admin".equalsIgnoreCase(password))){
        return "result";
    }else{
        /*System.out.println("Enter Valid details");*/
        FacesMessage msg = new FacesMessage("Authentication Failed.","Authentication Failed");
        msg.setSeverity(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR);
        return null;
    }
}
public void execute(){
    checkUser(name, password);
}
```

}

This is my XHTML Page.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"   
  xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
  xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core" >
<h:body>

<h1>Custom validator in JSF 2.0</h1> 

  <h:form >

    <h:panelGrid columns="3">

     User Name:

      <h:inputText  id="username" value="#{user.name}" 
        required="true" >
        <f:validateLength minimum="4" maximum="15" />
      </h:inputText>

      <h:message for="username" style="color:red" />
     Password : 
        <h:inputSecret id="password" value="#{user.password}" 
         required="true" >
        <f:validator validatorId="com.acc.validations.PasswordValidator" />
      </h:inputSecret>
    </h:panelGrid>

    <h:commandButton value="Submit"  action="#{user.execute}" />


        </h:form>

   </h:body>
 </html>
```

My Requirement is that if the user enters user name and password as "admin" the control should redirect to result.xhtml else it should display message in the facesContext that i had written in the contoller.
This is my result.xhtml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"   
  xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html">
<h:body>
 <h1>Custom validator in JSF 2.0</h1>
  <h:panelGrid columns="2">
    Welcome to User : 
    <h:outputText value="#{user.name}" />
  </h:panelGrid>
 </h:body>
 </html>
```

I am not able to render the result.xhtml eventhough i enter admin as username and password and also i am not getting any messages while i am entering wrong credentials.And also i am not getting any errors.Could u please help me in this regard in order to work as per my requirement.

Comment: Code. Where is the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried something like this :
In your .xhtml

```
<p:inputText id="j_username" required="true" value="#{login.nomLogin}" />
```

In your "controller"

```
@ManagedBean(name="login")
@SessionScoped

public class LoginBean implements Serializable {


        private String nomLogin;
        private Boolean isConnected = false;
        //Getter and Setter for this one

 public String checkValidUser(){
 //To see the value of login
 System.out.println("Login a pour valeur :"+ getNomLogin());
if((getNomLogin().equals("admin")== true){
 isConnected =true;
 return "ok";
}}}
```

This is how my login works, you can do the same thing with a boolean it depend of what you need.

I think you can test the value, if you have something like that :
 you can potentially test the valor of this , for example my menu is hidden if anybody is connected and show if admin is connected :

```
<p:panel id="HidePanel" header="Menu caché" rendered="#{login.isConnected == 'true'}"  />
```

Comment: Hi I am getting values to the controller i have to display validation messages if the condition that i have mentioned above is true or false.How can i get messages from the controller

Comment: Plop, I have edited my answer with an exemple of testing controller value. Can you edit your first message with some exemples of code to see exactly what you trying to do please ^_^